# Import custom field options from one Infusionsoft app to another

Tags: infusionsoft

I am trying to find a way to update a custom field automatically within multiple Partner Infusionsoft apps when I manually update the field with new options within our main Infusionsoft app.

The idea is to avoid manually logging into every Partner Infusionsoft app that we manage, individually, to update the custom field options so that they match our main app custom field options when it is updated. The custom field is constantly being updated with new options that need to be mirrored within all of our partner apps.

The process would not need to be entirely automatic. We could manage using a trigger to update the rest of the apps whenever we have manually updated the custom field in our main app.

Can anyone please steer me in the right direction or tell me if this isn't even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible with the API. Unfortunately there isn't a REST webhook for when a custom field is modified, so it would require a constant poll against what you would consider the master application. Constantly check the custom field and see if it's values changed. This is the rest documentation for that:

https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/rest/#!/Contact/retrieveContactModelUsingGET

That will include all the possible options for the field.

Unfortunately you can't modify a custom field in the newer REST API so you will have to use xmlrpc. The rest API only let's you create according to the documentation.

Here are the docs for the endpoint you would use with xmlrpc to update all the other apps to match the master application.
https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#data
https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/table-schema/

DataFormField is the custom field information. You would use the data endpoint to modify the values.

Be careful when you are polling the master application to not go over usage limits and apply best practices.